# SQL IN Function Issue

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have created a page item as `P16_X` with values `998,785,523` in my oracle apex app. Then i have created a `Classic Report` in my apex page and added below code as `Region Source`.

```
  select 
   sale_date,
   invoice_number , 
   sale_amount from sale
    where sale_id in (:P16_X);
```

when i load my page i got below error.

```
  report error:
  ORA-01722: invalid number
```

How could i solve this ?

Comment: what is `P16_x`? is that from a query?

Comment: @JohnWoo `P16_X` is a `Page Item` in my apex page

Comment: The server won't magically decide that, where it's been passed a single string parameter, it ought to inspect the contents of that parameter, observer the commas, and turn it into 3 separate parameters. You wouldn't expect `in ('998,785,523')` to be equivalent to `in ('998','785','523')`, would you? What if the column you're performing an `in` against contains values containing commas? How could you use `in` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  select 
   sale_date,
   invoice_number , 
   sale_amount from sale
    where ','||:P16_X||',' like '%,'||sale_id||',%'
```

PS: when you send this parameter into the query oracle takes it as a string "998,785,523" so your original query fails because of that. In this query we get:

```
','||'998,785,523'||',' like '%,'||sale_id||',%'
```

it is equivalent to:

```
',998,785,523,' like '%,'||sale_id||',%'
```

for example for sale_id=523 it is converted into:

```
',998,785,523,' like '%,523,%'
```

and it's TRUE for this sale_id.

Comment: its worked. :) could you explain this part. `where ','||:P16_X||',' like '%,'||sale_id||',%'`

Comment: I can't upvote this correct answer because you haven't explained why this is not a good method of storing data.

Answer (score 0):

No idea about APEX but the issue is Oracle treats p16 as number but '998,785,523' looks for him as a string so by my opinion you should either add in any temporarty table these 3 values and use select from  in your IN clause or parse '998,785,523' and use it inIN clause as well or create your select statement using dinamic sql. I vote for my first suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating user input directly into your SQL is asking for SQL injection issues. Take a look at apex_util.string_to_table instead, it allows you to convert a CSV to an array usable in an IN construct.